# how to delete a value between <input> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating checkboxes using `JQuery` as following:

```
$('<input type="checkbox" ' + 'id=' + (i+1) + '>' + (i+1) + '</input><br/>')
```

Then later it is removed whenever the user checks the box in:

```
if (this.checked) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```

However, The input box is deleted, but the number (id) stays on the page, along the `<br/>` Tag, so I can see the `#i` there on the HTML Page.
I would like to remove them as well.
So, to in order to make my question as complete as possible, here is how the `HTML` is laid:

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox">
1
<br>
```

Could someone please give me a clue how to remove `#i` and `<br/>` from the page?
Thanks

Comment: `input` tags are self-closing. You cannot use them in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as stated by other answers - input don't have closing tags

You will still need to remove all `id` and `<br />`. You can find those with `.next()` function in jquery. You should put your id in `<label>` or `<span>`.
Then. for example:

```
$(this).next('label').remove();
$(this).next('br').remove();
$(this).remove();
```

Code can be written shorter but it's for you to see how it works.

Comment: And to remove the (i+1) when the <input> be deleted?

Comment: you can put it in e.g. `<span>` tag and remove it by `.next()` too

Answer (score 1):

that's because `input` tags don't have closing tags and `remove` ignores everything after the `>`,  change this:

```
$('<input type="checkbox" ' + 'id=' + (i+1) + '>' + (i+1) + '</input><br/>')
```

to:

```
$('<input type="checkbox" ' + 'id=' + (i+1) + 'value="' + (i+1) +'"><label>'+ (i+1) +'</label>')
```

```
$(this).next('label').andSelf().remove();
```

Comment: `+ '>' + (i+1) + '/>` did you just close it twice? -1

Comment: Also suggest him to use a label, and code for removing assosiated label+br would make the answer perfect :)

Comment: The `/` at the end is not valid in HTML4.

Comment: you guys are missing something ... the value of `(i+1)` does not get displayed anymore.

Comment: @philippe: use `$('<input type="checkbox" ' + 'id=' + (i+1) + 'value="' + (i+1) +'" /> '+(i+1)+'<br/>');`

Comment: @JerzyZawadzki
And to remove the `(i+1)` when the `<input>` be deleted?

Answer (score 1):

The text in [`<input>` text boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input) is not set with a textnode (like for textareas), but with the `value` attribute. (Sorry for the confusion)

Yet, you want to have a checkbox. Best, create a `<label>` for it, instead of a text node plus a `<br />` (which is not handleable with jQuery):

```
<div class="inputcell">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check5">
    <label for="check5">5</label>
</div>
```

With this DOM, you can easily remove the whole box by `$("#check5").parent().remove()`. Note that single numbers are no valid element ids.

Answer (score 0):

input tags don't have closing tag, to create a checkbox you just need the following:

```
$('<input type="checkbox" ' + 'id=' + (i+1) + '>');
```

and if you want also to use a label for that checkbox, create appropriate `label` or any other element, because you can't put closign tag for input and a text between them